# Why this simple query does not run optimal in mysql using partitions?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, partitioning

Under Mysql version 5.7.31, Ubuntu 18.04 8core cpu system with 24gb of ram, I have a table named mytable.
It is partitioned in 30 partitions using a HASH(YEAR(created_at)) function on a datetime field named created_at. It consists of a total of 185378420 records. It has a primary key using auto_increment named id.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytyable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=194156422 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (YEAR(created_at))
PARTITIONS 30 */
```

I am trying to run this simple query.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` IN (194070462,194070461) ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

I cannot understand why it gets stucked in sending data phase, while I am not sure if it ever completes succesfully.

On the other hand if i change the sort direction it runs very fast (in terms of miliseconds).

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` IN (194070462,194070461) ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

And also if I remove the order by clause competely

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` IN (194070462,194070461);
```

Both queries produce the expected output which is:

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| id        | created_at          |
+-----------+---------------------+
| 194070461 | 2021-07-26 21:16:47 |
| 194070462 | 2021-07-26 21:16:47 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

I believe it should be able to first gather the data and then try to sort them.

The explain is exactly the same for all 3 queries:

```
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions                                                                                                    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29 | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   20 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Any idea what is happening behind the curtains? Is it somehow a partitioning limitation, because of the combination of range query and order by desc clause? Is there any workouround for this?

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "9.62"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "mytable",
        "partitions": [
          "p0",
          "p1",
          "p2",
          "p3",
          "p4",
          "p5",
          "p6",
          "p7",
          "p8",
          "p9",
          "p10",
          "p11",
          "p12",
          "p13",
          "p14",
          "p15",
          "p16",
          "p17",
          "p18",
          "p19",
          "p20",
          "p21",
          "p22",
          "p23",
          "p24",
          "p25",
          "p26",
          "p27",
          "p28",
          "p29"
        ],
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "PRIMARY"
        ],
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "id"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 20,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 20,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "using_index": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "5.62",
          "eval_cost": "4.00",
          "prefix_cost": "9.62",
          "data_read_per_join": "11K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "created_at"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`mydb`.`mytable`.`id` in (194070462,194070461))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot run"? Do you get any errors? Do you get any result? Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616). Also check see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions and [edit] your question to include a more detailed description with the system you are using what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: For mysql-5.7, indexes are always stored in ascending order and iterating them in descending order has some limitations. Worth looking more into that.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with this, but i believe that this would not apply to such a simple case. The same query plays well in a similar database NON-PARTITIONED same version.

Comment: Once it finds the 2 (or fewer) rows with those presumably-unique ids, sorting 2 rows is no problem.

Comment: @user498529 - Show us the other main queries; we can advise on the optimal indexing and partitioning(if any).

Comment: In general, if you try to solve a database performance problem by splitting a table into ten partitions, now you have eleven problems. Hard drives and SSDs are orders of magnitude bigger and faster than they were when partititions were invented. They were invented in the days when 32GiB 7200rpm disk drives were cutting edge and DBMSs needed hacks to make bigger data fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITION BY HASH` is, in my opinion, totally useless, especially for performance.  Ditto for `SUBPARTITIONing` and any method other than `BY RANGE`.  Even then there are very few cases where it is useful.

In your situation...

Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` (or at least the *first* column in the PK or some secondary index?  If so, then:

`PARTITIONing` by anything other than `id` will involve looking in *every* partition.  Sure, it will use an index once it is there.  But that is 60 lookups to find 2 rows.  (60 = 2 items in IN times 30 partitions).  Apparently, it is even worse than this -- since it is "stuck", as you put it.

Without partitioning, it would be a simple 2 lookups.

`PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(created_at))` would be better than `BY HASH`, but not much better.  There are very few queries that would make effective use of "partition pruning".  And Hash can never us a "range" of dates for pruning.

Please show me `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main queries that are applied.  I'll advise on the optimal set of indexes to use and whether or not Partitioning of any benefit.  Another question:  Will you be purging "old" rows?  (Purging via `DROP PARTITION` is the main use for `BY RANGE` on a date.  But that only helps the `DELETE`, not `SELECTs`.)

**Change to InnoDB!**

Comment: I updated the question, including the schema. I can understand that my partition decision was bad, and that i could benefit some other things if i had choosen a range strategy for the same field. But I still cannot understand why the query containing the ORDER BY DESC clause cannot actually run.

Comment: Yeah partitioning features are tempting.  I'll stare at the DESC issue.

Comment: @user498529 please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` and see if they are identical among the 3 queries.

Comment: totally identical

Comment: @user498529 - May I see one of them.

Comment: @user498529 - Hmmm  How many rows in the table?  `"rows_examined_per_scan": 20` -- I would expect `2` in a non-partitioned table or 60 in your 30-partition table.  How many different "years" of data do you have?  Perhaps only 10?  (I'm guessing that the Optimizer sees that most partitions are empty and doesn't count them in Explain.)  Whether 20 or 60, it should be sub-second to run the query.

Comment: I believe it's something like a bug. I would test it later or tomorrow to find if it is due to mysql version, myisam engine, number of partitions or something else.

Comment: @user498529 - I missed the Engine.  Please change to InnoDB; many things improve; and most advice today _assumes_ InnoDB.  It's been years since optimizations have been added to the MyISAM engine.

Comment: Made a test with innodb, and as expected it works great. Also i found it works good for myisam for small id values. I will also make a last myisam check with this options which requires a version update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html#optflag_prefer-ordering-index